# Windows 7 - RCA audio to audio adapter

Tags: windows-7, audio, adapter, rca

My monitor has RCA audio male inputs and my PC has standart audio input. I want to connect the PC and the monitor in order to use the monitor's volume.

I have not done this before, so what I am doing maight be wrong.

So, I have look trought all "strange" cables that I have in my PC box and there was no cable that can connect the PC and the monitor. A quick resarch in the internet point me to RCA to audio adapter, in my case "male to two males":

[image]

Unfortunatelly, this is still not doing the trick. Can anyone advice what can I try?

I am using windows 7.

EDIT 1:

My audio card is build-in (Intel G-Series).
My monitor model is LG M2752D LG.

I am able to use the an second RCA female adapter with 2 colons. So, I gues the problem is the monitor.

EDIT 2:

In the monitor [tenichinal specifications](http://www.digitalversus.com/lcd-monitor/lg-m2752d-p13926/test.html)  is said:

> Audio is catered for by two 5-watt speakers. There's an audio
>   mini-jack for inputting audio from a PC connected via VGA or with a
>   DVI-to-HDMI cable. Plus, if you use the component connection, two RCA
>   ports are on hand for the audio signal.

Firstly, I have try to do this using the RCA ports. As I was able to get sound using the other RCA female adapter with sound colons directly to the PC, I am pretty sure the issue is not due to the computer.

After that, I get one DVI-to-HDMI cable. I was able to get picture (only have to change the resolution) but again no sound. So, I guess the DVI-to-HDMI is working, I just have to do something other to get the sound working too.

Comment: What monitor and what motherboard/sound card have you?

Comment: This is the monitor http://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-M2752D-monitor-tv - M2752D LG. I will try to find the what's the sound card. Anyway it is pretty old (5 years old PC) and  I hope the issue is not due to it :- )

Comment: Try to in the future update this in your post (by editing it), it sanitizes the comment box.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a language issue, but you say "my PC has standart audio input".  If you are connecting the audio INPUT on the PC to the monitor, it isn't going to work.  You need to connect the audio OUTPUT (typically a 3.5mm stereo jack that is ringed with a light green plastic) to the monitor.

Comment: I understood as the monitor having the RCA female ports on the back (which it has, you can see the pictures in the link the OP gave). With this in mind, maybe you just connected them wrong - maybe you connected the RCA to the composite video. If I recall, the sound ports are those on the right, next to the SCART port. I suppose you can check the users manual for the correct port.

Comment: I wonder if its somehow only using the RCA audio ports when you're using composite video in?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I did not get this. You mean if I am using the incorrect ports (video instead audio)?

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to plug in the yellow video cable and set that input as the active one for the red and white audio cables to work

Answer (score 1):

You need a DVI to HDMI cable with Audio Return (Audio Upstream Feature) - see this eBay link:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-5M-5FT-High-Speed-HDMI-DVI-Digital-Audio-Cable-DVI-D-Male-to-HDMI-Male-Cable-/350807682616?pt=US_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item51adc46e38

High speed HDMI cable with ethernet-supports 3D, Audio Return Channel and UP to 4K resolution
Compatible with 3D TV Technology
For TV DVD Xbox 360 PS3
LCD HDTV Plasma Cable
1.5m Cable Length(1.5M=5FT)
Connects A/V components with HDMI to a DVI input.
Connects computers with DVI output to HDMI components.
Delivers Up to 1080p Digital HDTV.
Connectors: HDMI Male/DVI Male
Pure copper conductors for maximum conductivity and bandwidth
4 Layers Shielding
Silver coated copper wire to reduce interference

Cheers,

Gary - Oz